# Basic C++ programming problems

Tags: c++

I am learning c++, i have completed a basic intro book. Now i have purchaced a book called 'Professional c++', its great, however...

There is example code in the book on how to write an employee database, i have completed that, but to get a better understanding i have thought about writing a program that is based on that program, but for a prison service. It generates random prison numbers etc. This is just the header file, i started work on it today and would like to know a few things.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

namespace Records
{
class Prisoner
{
public:
    Prisoner();                     //prisoner constructor
    void addTime(int years);
    void reduceTime(int years);
    void prisonNumber();
    void display();
    // getters and setters
    void setFirstName(const std::string& firstName); // 
    const std::string& getFirstName();


    // private data members
private:
    std::string mFirstName;
    std::string mLastName;

    int mPrisonNumber;

};
}
```

What i dont understand is the lines

```
void setFirstName(const std::string& firstName); // 
    const std::string& getFirstName();
```

My understanding is that it is a function that returns nothing (void), takes a string pointer argument called firstName.

I will define this function in the complimentary .cpp as follows;

```
void Prisoner::setFirstName(const string& firstName)
    { mFirstName = firstName;}
```

What would be the literal translation of what i am doing here?

I think that i am taking a string address of a string and assigning it to a data member...

If i must be honest i need to study what datamembers are and how they are used, i have completed exercises on pointers and classes, but i cant actually say in words what is going on. 
Could someone suggest some reading materials/ sources, so that i can increase my understanding. I had a look on amazon but was swamped by all the different books available.

Comment: Are you asking what data members are, or what `setFirstName` is doing?

Comment: These things are explained in any halfway-decent C++ tutorial. Which tutorial are you using for learning?

Comment: What setFirstName is doing. But i now realise, the fact i am asking that question shows that i need a greater understanding of data members. C++ programming is easy steps its called.

Comment: sorry for the double comment, could you point me in the direction of these halfway decent tutorials? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Prisoner::setFirstName(const string& firstName)
{ mFirstName = firstName;}
```

Would mean:
The function (method) setFirstName() attached to objects of type Prisoner requires a reference (avoids copying) to a string and promises to leave it untouched (constant).
It will then take the member mFirstName (implied owned by Prisoner) and copy that value into it.

Had there not been a const the value could be modified in place. It functionally makes no difference in your code, it's "just" a guard to make sure you don't modify something when you don't intend to.

The & after a type means it's a reference, so it will read the object you pass it directly instead of making a copy of it for its own use scoped to that function.

Lastly it sets a member of the class to that value by copying the contents, a member being a qualified piece of data attached to that class, in your case a very plain one which will then become Prisoner.mFirstName.

Notice how the exercise has you declaring the members as private, that means they can only be modified from inside the class' implementation, and not from outside by whatever code will "use" the objects produced by the class.

Because of that, and because you do want to be able to read and write that data, albeit in a controlled fashion, setter and getter methods are implemented that allow to change the data (member) owned by the class through those public functions (methods).

Some people swear by setter/getter, some people dislike it, ultimately it's just a design choice whether you want to keep data tied to an object as private and gate/manage all external access to it (public methods altering private data), or expose it directly (make those members public).

YouTube has a lot of good beginner level C++ courses these days. Book recommendations tend to be on the edge of the rules here on SO because I think they are considered a matter of opinion, but you can find some very popular questions, some wikified, that are the non-official list of recommended books.
Personally I've always liked Stroustrup's and I think he's owed money for being the daddy of C++ after all :) but he can be very terse and concise at times, to the point of requiring a disproportionate effort to read. His beginner Principles and Practice is certainly a good book for someone who wants to go over beginner material again though.

Answer (score 2):

```
const std::string &getFirstName();                /* Getter */
void setFirstName(const std::string &firstName);  /* Setter */
```

These functions gets a datamember value (**getter**) or sets the datamember value (**setter**).

Getters and setters are there so the user of the class doesn't need to get the datamember explicitly but rather through your function.

The reason behind getters and setters is so you can, as example, validate the string passed to the setter before setting it to the datamember.

---

By the way; `const std::string &firstName` is *not* a pointer but the address of the passed variable so the setter won't copy the passed string.

Comment: Maybe add something to clarify that `const string &firstName` is _not_ a pointer.

Comment: Thank you, cleared that up for me. Could you give me some titles of some books/sites that helped you on your way when learning how to program? algorithms/ data members etc?

Comment: @HMPARTICLE To be honest, the only book I learned from is a C book called: **Learn C the hard way**. I learned `C++` by practicing a lot and I used my knowledge about `C` in combination with `Java` (classes and getters/setters and other OOP stuff).

Answer (score 0):

A literal translation of...

```
void Prisoner::setFirstName(const string& firstName) {
   mFirstName = firstName;
}
```

... would be:

Copy the data of some external string, which you pass into member function setFirstName as 'firstName', into mFirstname, an in-class private string.

Comment: It does not "point to" - It makes a copy of